# Inline CSS ::selection doesn't working

Tags: css, inline, inline-styles

I want to use inline styling [via PHP], and need the `::selection` and `-moz-selection` properties to be changed. In this project, I need randomly changed colors after pages refresh for this property.

Apparently, the css property (that is set at first place in an external file) is more dominant than inline styling, even if I use `!important` for inline values.

Is there any way to get inline styling work for this special property?

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HDHA3/)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Pseudo-classes with inline styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles)

Comment: Are you open to using javascript..?

Comment: Yes, can you suggest something for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles).

You can't declare a pseudo class inline, only in a stylesheet (or using `<style>` in the head).

Answer (score 1):

[Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828327/how-to-override-external-css)  .

I think you are facing the same problem as on the given link . CSS just reads from  top to down, therefore anything lower in the code should be overwritten . you should have to check your code with element inspector to check what css are applied to your code.